# Better portfolio with 'case studies'

Tags: usability-study, use-cases

How can I make a better portfolio with case studies? I'm disappointed in peoples portfolios being like an art gallery, or not organized well. *I probably just need a good example.*

Comment: This got me thinking http://www.jeffgothelf.com/blog/you-dont-need-a-ux-portfolio/

Comment: I'm not a UX designer, but I include Agile and usability in my work. Design slideshows seem naive seem navie for hyrid-designer-programmers like myself. Clients and employers are expecting more than pretty pictures, right?

Comment: @FXquincy...that's an excellent question, really. I am also a mix of designer/dev but my portfolio is 90% visual design. I don't know if that's good or bad, but has gotten me some jobs where they were hiring for developer but then went "Oh, you can design, too!?". So that helps. But it's definitely a great point. I need to think about adding more UX and dev-centric elements I think.

Comment: @DA01 I want my case-studies to demonstrate writing and organization skill. It may eliminate some of the fear companies have hiring right-brainers like myself. I love how UX has raised the bar for designers, so I'm more of a planner now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FXquincy, you propably should describe all important aspects of some of your best projects. It may include features description, some sentences about innovative features you add, describe why are they so good, important, easy to use, include before/after comparison, user testing results

For visual designer, their works speaks for themselves, but in UX/UI design you should explain what you work consist of. Colleagues may read your level and benefits of hiring you from bare screens, but for potential employers you should explain these benefits explicitly: this will make work faster, uncluttering this screen will make it easier to work with for the first time, etc.

Take a look at http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/kommersant/ (these guys are really good of describing why are they so good).

Comment: Didn't get that at first. Show 'benefits and features', not just documenting how it was made. Thanks. – FXquincy

Answer (score 2):

My own case studies roughly follow this outline:

Head:

- Project Title
- Images
- Subtitle (1-sentence synopsis)
- Roles & responsibilites
- Date
- Awards/recognition
- Keywords
- Technology

Body:

- Briefing (client, problem, restraints, goals)
- Solution (discoveries & concept)
- Result & benefits

BTW, even in case of visual/communication designers the works do *not* speak for themselves, IMNSHO. There is always some problem to solve and the solution does not necessarily make the original starting point nor the process obvious. A designer should in any case be able to explain *what* the original problem was, *how* they arrived at the chosen solution and *why* they think it succeeds (benefits, added value, …).

Answer (score 2):

The main Idea is to tell to story of your project, background info like what was the business requirements what was the brif, who else worked on this project with you, and what was your role, show your process and explain about your research, the different solutions you offered and what the costumer chose to advance with and why, tell about the user testing and all of the post development work you made. 
here is a very good [Article](http://www.creativebloq.com/ux/product-portfolios-61412126) that can get you started, pay close attention to [this](http://simonpan.com/) portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple portfolios online both of which i realise are not that good.

If I were to get a portfolio from someone here's what I would want to see in it

1)A short summary of you "I am a UXer with 5 years industry experience". Cool! i got it

2)A couple of projects you worked on where you describe what the application was for, for who, what problem it was fixing, how you went about the solution, the results.

that's it. And maybe something about you that I might find interesting, that you're not a dull person "I like Japanese death metal"

Answer (score 0):

http://tarng.com/-2011/ Very good case studies. Unfortunately his old site breaks in Chrome. You have to use safari to view.